# MongoDB merge two collections and drop documents with same value in field

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

In my database I have two collections, but some documents were added (possibly) at different times to both collections.

I could use `mongodump` and then `mongorestore` for merging. But then I have the same documents that were added to both collections as duplicates in my new collection. `mongorestore --drop` does not help neither, because the documents not necessarily have the same `_id`.

How to drop a document when a document with `userid` exists already?

Comment: Welcome to the StackExchange. what is MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: I use MongoDB v3.6.5
(build environment:
    distmod: debian92
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

There might be more elegent solutions for this, but let me answer how I merged a new collection into an original collection without importing the duplicates.

1. Compare `userid` fields in both collections and take the difference.
2. Use mongos [`$out` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to save documents to a difference collection. This new collection has all documents of the new collection, except of the duplicates.
3. `mongodump` the difference collection and `mongorestore` it into the original collection.

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
import subprocess

# collection names
db_name = 'db'
col_original = 'col_original'
col_new = 'col_new'
field = 'userid'


# Get ids from collection
def get_ids(db, col):
    docs = db[col].aggregate([
        {'$project':
         {'_id': 0,
          'id': '$' + field}}
    ])
    docs = list(docs)
    ids = [x['id'] for x in docs]
    return ids


# Connect to MongoDB
client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost')
db = client[db_name]

# Get difference in ids
ids_new = get_ids(db, col_new)
ids_original = get_ids(db, col_original)
ids_diff = list(set(ids_new).difference(ids_original))

# Get all documents with userid that are in col_new, but not in
# col_original. Hence, all duplicates are skipped.
db[col_new].aggregate([
    {'$match': {
        field: {'$in': ids_diff}}},
    {'$out': 'col_diff'}])

# Use mongodump to save col_diff
subprocess.check_output(['mongodump',
                         '-d',
                         db_name,
                         '-c',
                         'col_diff'])

# Merge col_diff into col_original
subprocess.check_output(['mongorestore',
                         '-d',
                         db_name,
                         '-c',
                         col_original,
                         'dump/' + db_name + '/col_diff.bson'])
```